# failing to install Flask package in pycharm

Tags: python, pip

after press install package its failing and giving me this below error

Looking in indexes: https://www.palletsprojects.com/p/flask/
Collecting Flask

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask

I have tried to to put python in windows path to no success please help

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it in your terminal : pip install flask

It should install the newest version